# Monitor Server Blade Components using snmpwalk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp

Is it possible to monitor sun blade server components,/SYS (host system) Motherboard /SYS/MB, /SYS/SP Service processor etc using snmp. By using snmp i was able to get chasis temp, Fan speed, Voltage. When i traversed Entitty MIB i didnt get any Values starting with /SYS. If i am wrong please correct me, is there any way to monitor individual blade components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with then SNMP "exec" directive. It will enable you to write a shell script to check whatever you want and let snmp execute that script and get it's result.
Documentation is available man pages